# My 32bits Windows 7 using only 2.39Gb over 6Gb installed

Tags: windows-7, memory, 32-bit

I've just bought a 6Gb RAM PC and reinstalled Windows 7 32 bits on it. I remarked :

> 6 Gb installed, 2.39 Gb usable.

How to use all the installed memory ?

Comment: By installing a 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 bit operating systems are limited in how much RAM they can utilize. This is a common problem for 32 bit systems, and can lead to a lot of issues with various intensive programs (think: Adobe suites, video editing, etc.)

A 64 bit operating system can theoretically use [16.8 Million Terrabytes](http://www.howtogeek.com/175443/what-is-the-maximum-amount-of-ram-you-could-theoretically-put-in-a-64-bit-computer/) of RAM, but in actuality your 6GB installed would work. Ergo, the answer is upgrade to 64 bit.

Comment: I was worrying about compatibility issues for some 32 bits programs.

Comment: That will be an issue, but unfortunately, unless you can find alternatives to those 32 bit programs and retire them, you will need to stay on a 32 bit operating system. You may need to research those programs and figure out if they will run on a 64 bit OS, but I know from experience that some very old programs will simply not run in a 64 bit environment.

Comment: win64 can run 32 bir apps but it cant run 16 bit ones.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan not always. The company I work for uses a program called MSSI for some users, and this program will not run on a 64 bit system. There are others like it which are the same way, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

> How to use all the installed memory ?

By installing an OS that can address that memory. E.g. windows 7 64 bit.

Might be a short answer, but there is good reason why we have used 64 bit operating systems for quite some time now. 32 bit memory limit were not a problem on 32MB systems, nor a few years after those. But once you get to the XP era 32 bit was often very limiting. The only reason not to install a normal 64 bit version was driver incompatibility. Those have long since been fixed.

So unless you have a few decade old piece of software which needs a 32 bit OS, simply start with a non-cripped base. E.g. windows 64 bit.